# When accessing dictionary values, how to impute 'NaN' if no value exists for a certain key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nan, key-value

I am looping through dictionaries and accessing the dictionary values to append to a list.

Consider one dictionary as an example, `example_dict`:

```
example_dict = {"first":241, "second": 5234, "third": "Stevenson", "fourth":3.141592...}
first_list = []
second_list = []
third_list = []
fourth_list = []
...
first_list.append(example_dict["first"])  # append the value for key "first"
second_list.append(example_dict["second"])  # append the value for key "second"
third_list.append(example_dict["third"])     # append the value for key "third"
fourth_list.append(example_dict["fourth"])   # append the value for key "fourth"
```

I am looping through hundreds of dictionaries. It is possible that some keys do not have values. In this case, I would like an `NaN` appended to the lists---after running the script, each list should have the same number of elements.

If `new_dict = {"first":897, "second": '', "third": "Duchamps", ...}`, then `second_list.append(new_dict["second"])` would append `NaN`.

How does one write in a check for this to occur? An if statement?

Comment: Use the `.get` method; `'NaN'` would be a string: `second_list.append(new_dict.get('second', 'NaN'))`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye you could also use `float('nan')`.

Comment: Note that technically, a value *does* exist in this case, namely the empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a check for values that are not `""` and simply do something like this:

```
second_list.append(new_dict["second"] if new_dict["second"] != "" else "NaN"))
```

So, if key `second` exists in `new_dict` and is an empty string, then `NaN` will be appended to `second_list`.

If you were looking to create a list of values from the dictionary applying the logic above, you can do the following, both are the same, first is expanded, and the second is the shortened comprehension:

## method 1

```
new_dict = {"first":897, "second": '', "third": "Duchamps"}
new_list = []
for _, v in new_dict.items():
    if v != "":
        new_list.append(v)
    else:
        new_list.append('NaN')
```

## method 2 (comprehension)

```
new_dict = {"first":897, "second": '', "third": "Duchamps"}
new_list = [v if v != "" else 'NaN' for _, v in new_dict.items()]
```

Comment: Looks like the missing value is an empty string `""`. In that case, replace `new_dict.get("second", "NaN")` with `new_dict["second"] if new_dict["second"] != "" else "NaN"`. A list comprehension might be cleaner.

Comment: @SethDifley Thanks for bringing that to my attention, I somehow missed that. Updating my answer.

Comment: The user @MosesKoledoye mentioned using `.get()`. This seems to be the shortest answer---how does it hold up to the above answers?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang My original answer actually used `get` if you check the edit on my answer. But it was realized that your use case needs to check if the key exists but there is no value for the key. When using `get('second', 'NaN')`, it will return `NaN` only if the *key* does not exist in the dictionary, which is not what you want. Read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) on get. You will see that it does not match your use case based on what you explained in your question.

Comment: So, to clarify: `new_dict = {"first":897, "second": '', "third": "Duchamps"}
new_list = [v if v != "" else 'NaN' for _, v in new_dict.items()]`
Let's say we want to access only certain dictionary keys, e.g. `first`. This is my goal. In this case, our option is to use `new_dict["second"] if new_dict["second"] != "" else "NaN"`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang I'm not sure I understand. Are you confirming whether the answer addresses your goal? Or are you introducing a new edge case now?

Comment: @idjaw I'm not sure answer addresses the question: In your case, `method1` and `method2` search the entire dictionary for key values, and appends the values if exist, NaN otherwise. In my task detailed above, each list must access a specific key. So, instead of `new_dict = {"first":897, "second": '', "third": "Duchamps"}; new_list = [v if v != "" else 'NaN' for _, v in new_dict.items()]`, it should be something like `new_dict = {"first":897, "second": '', "third": "Duchamps"}; first_key_list = [new_dict["first"] if new_dict["first"] != "" else 'NaN' ]`. Agreed?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang From the code you provided, you seem to creating several lists, where each list you are appending an explicit value from your dictionary. I provided that at the top of my solution. I *could* delete the bottom part of my solution that shows how to apply that logic in the context of creating a list of values from a dictionary. Your example of using `first_key_list`. Are you looking to create a new list that has a single value in it from the dictionary?

Comment: @idjaw You're right---I think the solution provided actually does show what I'm asking. The top of the solution works, and the bottom provides details---don't delete it. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Cheers @ShanZhengYang